# What are the implications and differences in installing gitlab via omnibus package vs. manual installation?

Tags: nginx, installation, gitlab, ubuntu-14.04

Why do I ask:

- the server (Ubuntu 14.04) does not only run gitlab but other services (based on node.js) for testing purposes (I only got the one server)
- therefore  I want to configure mainly nginx and other gitlab-omnibus dependencies the way I am used to
- I have to migrate from a manual installation (7.3 MySQL) to a [manual|omnibus] based one

  - (MySQL won't be used any more unless GitLab will be configured so for any reason you might wanna give me regarding migration)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a fairly recent Ubuntu, you could consider building a **[GitLab container image](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab)**, using **[Docker](https://www.docker.com/)**.
It scripts a manual installation into an independent light-weight VM (a container).

That way, you can isolate your GitLab setup from your other services, and easily replicate that setup.

An [omnibus setup](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md) is about installing the full stack needed to run GitLab (ruby, nginx, mysql, ...)

Comment: +1 for the nice option of docker. But for several reasons I cannot utilize docker for that. For instance I would have my coworkers to learn another technology.

Comment: @aaki I agree. I just wanted to point out a new way to isolate multiple services on a single server (in multiple containers)